# use of samlKeystore.jks in Spring SAML extension

Tags: spring, single-sign-on, adfs2.0, spring-saml

I am new to SSO and Sping SAML extension.
i have implemented Spring SAML extension into our application where our application acts as a SP. i have following question related to our requirement.

1) I would like to understand the use of samlKeystore.jks in Spring saml extension
2) I would like to know if we can skip the use of samlKeystore.jks in any manner.
   Basically the reason for this the client can give us information on Just the meta data
   and nothing apart from that.if we are using samlKeystore.jks do we need anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keystore is used for storage of private certificates used to digitally sign messages created by the Service Provider and decrypting of messages sent from Identity Providers.

Spring SAML currently requires you to have at least a default key available, even in case it won't get used.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to sign SAML protocol message or encrypt SAML assertions you don't need the keystore. However some SAML Bindings mandates or at least highly recommend to sign so that the protocol messages are not tampered with at the user agent.